# Filter a query by Date

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I have the following query

```
var query =  
                     from f in _db.Production
                     join g in _db.Run on f.show equals g.Production.show


                     select new ViewProductions {
                            Venuename = g.venue,
                            Showname = f.show,

                            StartDate = g.startDate,
                            EndDate = g.endDate


                     };

        return View(query);
```

How would i add a where clause that would say

Where start date is in the next 3 months from today?

Thanks

**Update**

Working code

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var limit = now.AddDays(90);
        var query =
        from f in _db.Production
        join g in _db.Run on f.show equals g.Production.show
        where g.endDate >= now && g.startDate <= limit


                    select new ViewProductions
                    {
                        Venuename = g.venue,
                        Showname = f.show,
                        StartDate = g.startDate,
                        EndDate = g.endDate
                    };



        return View(query);
```

Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can't use any `DateTime.Add*` methods in linq-to-sql or entity framework, you'll have to use variables:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var limit = now.AddDays(90);
var query =  from f in _db.Production
             join g in _db.Run on f.show equals g.Production.show
              where g.StartDate >= now && g.StartDate <= limit
              select new ViewProductions {
                      Venuename = g.venue,
                      Showname = f.show,
                      StartDate = g.startDate,
                      EndDate = g.endDate    
                     };
```

Comment: This did not output any data either

Comment: well, I can't guess your schema.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I have it working now just needed to switch dates round. I have updated my question to include the correct code.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Linq to Sql/Entities you will have to calculate the date first, then use it in the query:

```
DateTime futureDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
from f in _db.Production
join g in _db.Run on f.show equals g.Production.show
where g.StartDate <= futureDate && g.StartDate >= DateTime.Now
...
```

Comment: It is 3 months and not 30 days.

Comment: Three months certainly aren't 30 days.

Comment: Have tried this and it does not output any data, from the logic it seems as though it should though

Comment: Have you tried playing with the time frames? What data do you have that would qualify?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line yo your query:

```
var query =  
from f in _db.Production
join g in _db.Run on f.show equals g.Production.show
where g.startDate > DateTime.Today && 
g.startDate < DateTime.Today.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(90))
 ....
```